# UnitTest Python Mock first call to method, second call go as usual

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I am mocking a method. I want to raise an exception on the first call, but on exception, I am calling that method again with different parameters, so I want the second call to be processed normally. What do I need to do?

### Code

#### Try 1

```
with patch('xblock.runtime.Runtime.construct_xblock_from_class', Mock(side_effect=Exception)):
```

#### Try 2

```
with patch('xblock.runtime.Runtime.construct_xblock_from_class', Mock(side_effect=[Exception, some_method])):
```

On the second call, `some_method` is returned as it is, and data is not processed with different parameters.

Answer (score 4):

```
class Foo(object):
  def Method1(self, arg):
    pass

  def Method2(self, arg):
    if not arg:
      raise
    self.Method1(arg)

  def Method3(self, arg):
    try:
      self.Method2(arg)
    except:
      self.Method2('some default value')

class FooTest(unittest.TestCase):
  def SetUp(self):
    self.helper = Foo()

  def TestFooMethod3(self):
    with mock.patch.object(self.helper, 'Method2', 
                           side_effect=[Exception,self.helper.Method1]
                           ) as mock_object:
      self.helper.Method3('fake_arg')
      mock_object.assert_has_calls([mock.call('fake_arg'),
                                    mock.call('some default value')])
```

Comment: I want second iteration to call the method and process data. `side_effect=[Exception, 'some_other_outcome']` What would be the syntax?

Comment: What is `some_other_outcome `?

Comment: You're mocking out a method so all you can do is assert that the method was called a second time with the expected params. If the method you are mocking isn't tested then test it separately.